# Imprimir no console todos os valores do formulário com JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma forma de capturar todos os dados selecionados nos `selects` e inseridos nos inputs de um formulário?

Já tentei usando `$('#form1').serialize();` mas não obtive resultado, no php utilizo a variável global `$_GET` e `$_POST` e utilizo o `var_dump()` para imprimir os resultados, queria saber como posso fazer isto no jquery?

Comment: Porque o `$('#form1').serialize()` não funcionou? O que aconteceu?

Comment: @ArturoTemplário não sei se pode ser o fato do formulário ser dinâmico e os dados ele entende que ainda não existam, por ter sido criado após a declaração da função

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta serializar com `serializeArray` e transformar em 
`JSON`.

```
var dados = JSON.stringify( $(#form1).serializeArray() ); //  <-----------

console.log( dados );
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica, mas só funciona para `inputs` sabe se tem como pegar os valores dos selects também?

Comment: Esse método pega todos os inputs, revise seu select, pode ser que a estrutura ou names estejam incorretos, qualquer coisa edite a pergunta com eles.

Comment: você tinha razão os meus `selects` estavam sem o atributo `name`, acrestei e agora funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Bem pelo que vi o serialize() não serviu, então como você quer apenas obter os valores dos inputs e dos selects. Pode usar o $.each(). Da seguinte forma :

```
$(function(){
  var print=function(){
    var data = {};
    $('#form1 input, #form1 select').each(function(){
      data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(data);
  };

  print(); // irá printar o objeto no console
});
```

Basicamente o que esse código faz é ir em cada select e em cada input presente dentro do form, pegar o atributo name e seu valor. Depois e adiciona isso ao objeto data de tal modo que o, a chave seja o name do campo (que pode ser input ou select) e o valor seja o valor do campo.

Englobado dentro de uma função, ela pode ser chamada quando e da forma que precisar.

Espero ter ajudado ;)